REF200UA current source issue with multiple voltage supplies


This is my first question on stack exchange, so if I don't follow any rules I apologize in advance and will try to modify my question to meet expectations!
I'm working on a project where the goal is to supply a specified current to the skin. I've found in my research that the skin can be modeled as a combination of resistances and capacitances. I've also found that the resistances and capacitances can change with voltage. The main takeaway is that the resistance of the electrode + skin interface can vary significantly and is difficult to know in advance.
To that end, I'm using a cascade of the REF200UA 0.1 mA current sources and relay IC DG412. So far, I've found that when I use a sufficiently large supply voltage and the load of the electrode + skin interface is sufficiently low, I'm able to cascade a number of these current sources to obtain nearly any current. However, the problem I have is when the load of the electrodes + skin is too large and the required supply voltage exceeds the limits of the REF200UA. Of course, the circuit is still limited by Ohm's law. To circumvent this, I have attempted to supply sets of current sources separately. My hope was that two sets of current sources that are combined in parallel would result in the currents summing up. However, I'm finding that the current output is limited by the individual voltage supplies.
To analyze the problem, I've recreated it in a small example circuit. I've attached a schematic of that circuit here.
Current source: REF200UA (0.1 mA per source), Relay: Vishay DG412, VS1 = VS2 = 5 V, Load = 10 KOhm. The voltage that should be required to drive the load is about 5.5 V, as each current source requires 1 V to drive the 10 KOhm load and the sources require about 1.5 V in operation. I tested with a common supply (i.e. VS1 and VS2 are the same supply) with 5.5V, and the output is 0.4 mA, no problem. However, the output of the circuit when tested with separate 5 V supplies is ~0.37 mA. Even two separate 3.5 V supplies should be enough to drive the two sets of current sources each, and I would have expected the currents to add up as they are wired in parallel.
Am I missing a principle? Do the REF200UA current sources not work with separate supplies as I am expecting them to?
Thanks a ton in advance for any advice!

How are you measuring current?

Using a multimeter in series between the current sources and the load. I don't have the model name of the multimeter at the moment unfortunately.

Raise the supplies to +6V, and see if you get the full 0.4mA. If you do, then you know this is a compliance voltage problem, and you are operating too close to the typically-1.4V limit.

I'm not with the system currently, but I  remember when testing before that if the independent supplies are raised to 6 V, the correct 0.4 mA is output. That said, a single supply of 6 V in this case is sufficient to get the 0.4 mA. I'm more uncertain of why a combination of two 5 V supplies (each sufficient for 0.2 mA) aren't adding up to the total 0.4 mA. Thank you for the reply, by the way!

See my answer below

I originally deleted this answer, because I realised it didn't answer your question. However, it might illustrate why sharing a single voltage source, or using separate supplies, will make no difference.

Update:
You have understood that if the sources were ideal, with infinite compliance voltage, this problem wouldn't occur. These aren't ideal, though. By symmetry of the system, where no source is different from any other, it should be no surprise that all sources would be trying equally to lift the load voltage beyond their limit, and all sources will fail equally badly. All sources will share an equal fraction (1/4) of the deficiency of the available voltage, and all sources will fail to attain their rated current by the same amount.
KCL, KVL and Ohm's law are always obeyed, as you would expect, and are indeed sufficient to describe this system entirely. If you applied those laws to solve for the state of this system, you would obtain a result that agrees with the simulation, and reality. KCL is never broken, neither are KVL and Ohm's law, but (importantly) they must all be true simultaneously.
So when you apply KCL by saying that if each individual source is able to supply X amperes of current, then all four should supply 4X, this is correct in isolation, and for ideal sources, but fails to account for other constraints imposed by KVL and Ohm's law. I think you have applied KCL to the sources in isolation, without regard to the other laws at work in the entire system, and that is your mistake.
I feel that you are treating those sources of current as if current were some independent entity, and by using separate voltage sources to derive each "chunk" of current, they are somehow going to add up. That's true for hypothetical ideal current sources, which have infinite energy at their disposal, but not in real life. From a simple energy perspective, the highest potential energy available to any group of charges in the system is 5.5 joules-per-coulomb (volts), whether there are multiple voltage sources or not, and nothing you do (unless you employ charge-pumps, DC-DC converters or ideal sources) can endow charges anywhere in the system with more than that.

Ideal current sources are able to produce whatever potential difference across them that is necessary to pass their rated current through whatever is connected to them, but real-life current sources are not. Their potential difference is constrained by whatever power supply voltage they have at their disposal.
This "maximum" potential difference that a real-life current source can produce is called "compliance voltage", so named because they are able to "comply" (to produce the expected current) only until the required potential difference to pass that current is unachievable.
Below are two 100μA current sources. Source I1 on the left is ideal, with unlimited compliance voltage. Source B on the right emulates a real-life source, able to comply only up until the required potential difference exceeds its own supply voltage. This "clamping" is achieved using the ideal diode D1:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As you can see on the left, voltmeter VM1 clearly shows the source producing a potential potential of +10V (way beyond the supply of +5V) required to push 100μA through a 100kΩ load. Consequently, the full load current 100μA can be achieved through R1.
By contrast, on the right, a real current source is unable to comply, unable to apply a potential at node B beyond its own supply of +5V, and therefore only 5V appears across R2, and only 50μA can be achieved.
It's easy to see the onset of this limitation of compliance voltage if I plot the potentials \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$ as I sweep the resistance of R1 and R2 from 1kΩ to 100kΩ:

There we see the right-hand source (in orange) complying perfectly well, producing the exact voltage necessary to pass the requisite 100μA through R2, up until that required voltage exceeds the +5V supply. At that point the source can't produce the necessary voltage to ensure 100μA through the load, and it gets stuck at the maximum that it can provide, which is:
$$ I_{MAX} = \frac{V_{MAX}}{R_2} = \frac{+5V}{R_2} $$
This limitation of compliance voltage is what you are seeing in your own circuit. It always true that current sources in parallel will produce the sum of their currents in some common load, in accordance with Kirchhoff's Current Law, but what you've failed to consider is that the sources themselves aren't able to comply, and are producing well below their rated value.
The simple truth is that to pass 100μA through a 100kΩ resistor, you require \$V=I \times R=100\mu A \times 100k\Omega = 10V\$, and if none of your paralleled sources can achieve that, then even a million of them won't help:

simulate this circuit
You can see each source producing only 12.5μA, in spite of being rated to produce 100μA. When R1 is too large, they are all crippled by their inadequate supply of +5V, all unable to comply.
The only way to get 100μA through 100kΩ is with 10V, and to achieve that with real-life current sources, you require a voltage source exceeding 10V, and then you need only one:

simulate this circuit

I think the first part of your answer I’m aware of. The voltage output of the source can't exceed the input.
Let’s take the circuit on the right in the first set of schematics given. Even though the 5 V supply is below the required voltage, it produces 50 µA. In the case where four sources are used, that same source is now outputting 12.5 µA. I would have expected 50 µA. In the case that two sources are used, I’m confused why each doesn’t produce 50 µA and total 100 µA when combined in parallel. Thanks in advance. Sorry if I’m missing the point, I’m genuinely trying to understand.

@ECPZ You have understood that if the sources were ideal, with infinite compliance voltage, this problem wouldn't occur. These aren't ideal, though. By symmetry of the system, where no source is different from any other, it should be no surprise that all sources would be trying equally to lift the load voltage beyond their limit, and all sources will fail equally badly. All sources will share an equal fraction (1/4) of the deficiency of the available voltage, and all sources will fail to attain their rated current by the same amount...

@ECPZ KCL, KVL and Ohm's law are always obeyed, as you would expect, and are indeed sufficient to describe this system entirely. If you applied those laws to solve for the state of this system, you would obtain a result that agrees with the simulation, and reality. KCL is never broken, neither are KVL and Ohm's law, but (importantly) they must all be true simultaneoulsy...

@ECPZ So when you apply KCL by saying that if each individual source is able to supply X amperes of current, then all four should supply 4X, this is correct in isolation, but fails to account for other constraints imposed by KVL and Ohm's law. I think you have applied KCL to the sources in isolation, without regard to the other laws at work in the entire system, and that is your mistake.

@ECPZ I feel that you are treating those sources of current as if current were some independent entity, and by using separate voltage sources to derive each "chunk" of current, they are somehow going to add up. That's true for ideal current sources, but not here. By simple conservation of energy, the highest potential energy available to any group of charges in the system is 5.5 joules-per-coulomb (volts), separate sources or otherwise, and nothing you do (unless you employ charge-pumps, DC-DC converters or ideal sources) can endow charges anywhere in the system with more than that.

I think you've pinpointed the root of the misunderstanding. I'm considering KCL and Ohm's law, but not simultaneously considering KVL. Thank you very much for your explanation and patience. I accepted the answer.

Using a multimeter as an ammeter, in series with the load, the multimeter has several 10s or 100s of ohms of resistance which will develop a voltage (especially on low current ranges). This is its "sense" resistance, and the voltage across that resistance is "burden" voltage.
This burden voltage, which could be well over 0.1V, will "remove" some of the voltage which would normally be available to the load, effectively decreasing sources' compliance voltage (typically 1.4V less than the positive supply, for the REF200 in this configuration).
Measure voltage across your load resistance with a single 100μA source, and use Ohm's law to calculate its exact resistance. Then you can use that value with Ohm's law to determine current, only by measuring load voltage instead, which will not have such a detrimental affect on source compliance.
If I'm right, then without the ammeter in the current path, the voltage across the load should be able to reach the full 4V, and you will have the 400μA you expected.

By the way, the use of separate 5V supplies makes no difference. 5V is 5V wherever you get it from! This is surely not an issue of sharing supplies, or using separate supplies for different current sources.

I will give this a shot when I'm back at my circuit. Thanks!
